# Calling a procedure twice crashes my masm program

Tags: function, assembly, x86, procedure, masm

and thanks for taking the time.
With some help from stackoverflow and my professor, i managed to write a procedure that draws a 32 by 32 image to the window, using masm assembly and a library called canvas.lib.
However, back home i realized that when i call it twice it crashes my little game.
Here is the procedure definition.

```
drawimage proc
push ebp
mov ebp, esp
sub esp, 12
pusha

mov ecx, 0
outerloop:
cmp ecx, sprite_height
je done
mov ebx, 0

innerloop:
mov [ebp-8], ecx
mov [ebp-12], ebx
pusha
mov eax, [ebp-8]
mov ebx, sprite_width
mul ebx
add eax, [ebp-12]
shl eax, 2
mov esi, [ebp+8]
add esi, eax
push [esi]
pop [ebp-4]
mov eax, [ebp+20]
add eax, [ebp-8]
mov ebx, area_width
mul ebx
add eax, [ebp-12]
add eax, [ebp+16]
shl eax, 2
mov esi, [ebp+12]
add esi, eax
mov eax, [ebp-4]
mov dword ptr [esi], eax
popa

cmp ebx, sprite_height
je innerloopdone
inc ebx
jmp innerloop
innerloopdone:
inc ecx
jmp outerloop
done:
popa
mov esp, ebp
pop ebp
ret 12
drawimage endp
```

The function definition would look like this in c

```
void drawimage(int* image, int* windowmatrix, int x, int y);
```

I am calling the function here twice and the program crashes.

```
draw proc
push ebp
mov ebp, esp

push 240
push 320
push area
push offset bomb
call drawimage
add esp, 16

push 32
push 32
push area
push offset bomb
call drawimage
add esp, 16

mov esp, ebp
pop ebp
ret
draw endp
```

Bomb is a 32 x 32 matrix of 32 bit pixels, and area is a pointer to an allocated memory of 640 x 480 pixels. The memory used for area is allocated with malloc, so the value stored in area is in fact a pointer.
My guess is there is something i am not reverting back to normal in the function, but i still can't see why calling the function only once works normally. Any ideas?

Comment: `ret 12` doesn't do what you think it does. You just want a `ret`. For the future, learn to use a debugger. And comment your code, especially if you want others to help.

Comment: @Jester That was insanely fast, thank you. A quick look over the documentation and i realized my mistake. It might be too late night for code, that was a stupid mistake. Thanks for the suggestion with the debugger. Unfortunately, i can not select a comment as answer.